# ArcGIS symbology mis-categorizing data points

Tags: symbology, arcgis-online, classification

Wondering if anyone has run into this issue with Arc before. I've set up a simple symbology categorized into groups by parcel size.

Size Categories:

[image]

This appears to be calculating correctly for the most part, however a handful of data points are being styled as "Other" when they should be placed in a specified category. For example this data point is being styled as if it were out of range when parcel size attribute is within 0-10 acres.

[image]

I'm mostly confused as to why this is an occasional thing, if none of my points were rendering correctly I would assume that there was a problem with my data or with the symbology classes I set, however like I mentioned earlier this is only happening for some tens of points out of thousands.

Comment: The point you give as exemple has a "." (dot) as decimal separator, maybe a "," is expected.

Comment: If you can share the web map and layer can help us look into the issue.

Comment: Here's the link to the web map. i have published just one of the three layers but they are all having this issue. https://serecon-ag.maps.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=98407cba4b7546adb59ce355a2b07eb5

Comment: Looking at the provided map I think its a possible data issue and maybe a bug I have to look into further with the popup. If you pull up the data tab and look at that feature's(FID=405) PARCEL_SIZE_ACRE value its 3.16386651116999e+37 which pops it out of the max value for the layer styling which is 180.

Comment: Thanks for looking into this @RussRoberts I believe you identified my issue; values way out of range that were in scientific notation in excel show up without the notation in the popup screen end up looking like they are in range but they are being treated in the classification calculation as the out of range value that they are. Sometimes ya get going and miss the forest for the trees, thanks for pointing this out for me.

Comment: no sweat, and I have an issue in for the popup bug for 3.x JSAPI where we see the popup treating the 3.16e37 as just 3.16. This is working in 4.x JSAPI apps so the popup would display the info correctly and we would have seen the data issue right away.